# Dividing components of a vector into several data points in R

Tags: r, vector, statistics

I am trying to turn a vector of length n (say, 14), and turn it into a vector of length N (say, 90).  For example, my vector is

```
 x<-c(5,3,7,11,12,19,40,2,22,6,10,12,12,4)
```

and I want to turn it into a vector of length 90, by creating 90 equally "spaced" points on this vector- think of x as a function.  Is there any way to do that in R?

Comment: Do you want the new vector to have the element of the old vector? This can be done only if the min of the consecutive differences divides each consecutive differences....

Comment: Some desired output would help.  Do you want to interpolate between the points?

Comment: What about `approx`?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
> x<-c(5,3,7,11,12,19,40,2,22,6,10,12,12,4)
> seq(min(x),max(x),length=90)
 [1]  2.000000  2.426966  2.853933  3.280899  3.707865  4.134831  4.561798
 [8]  4.988764  5.415730  5.842697  6.269663  6.696629  7.123596  7.550562
[15]  7.977528  8.404494  8.831461  9.258427  9.685393 10.112360 10.539326
[22] 10.966292 11.393258 11.820225 12.247191 12.674157 13.101124 13.528090
[29] 13.955056 14.382022 14.808989 15.235955 15.662921 16.089888 16.516854
[36] 16.943820 17.370787 17.797753 18.224719 18.651685 19.078652 19.505618
[43] 19.932584 20.359551 20.786517 21.213483 21.640449 22.067416 22.494382
[50] 22.921348 23.348315 23.775281 24.202247 24.629213 25.056180 25.483146
[57] 25.910112 26.337079 26.764045 27.191011 27.617978 28.044944 28.471910
[64] 28.898876 29.325843 29.752809 30.179775 30.606742 31.033708 31.460674
[71] 31.887640 32.314607 32.741573 33.168539 33.595506 34.022472 34.449438
[78] 34.876404 35.303371 35.730337 36.157303 36.584270 37.011236 37.438202
[85] 37.865169 38.292135 38.719101 39.146067 39.573034 40.000000
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#data
x <- c(5,3,7,11,12,19,40,2,22,6,10,12,12,4)

#expected new length
N=90

#number of numbers between 2 numbers
my.length.out=round((N-length(x))/(length(x)-1))+1

#new data
x1 <- unlist(
  lapply(1:(length(x)-1), function(i)
    seq(x[i],x[i+1],length.out = my.length.out)))

#plot
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
plot(x)
plot(x1)
```

[image]